# How to set a channel as the homepage

Tags: routing

When users enter http://www.example.com I would like to redirect them to the http://www.example.com/news template.

How could I achieve this?

Comment: Do you mean proper redirecting? Or do you only want that news channel index template to be you home page?

Comment: I want the news channel to be my homepage. If possible redirect to the latest post in the news page.

Comment: "I want the news channel to be my homepage" is not that what you get with the `{% redirect %}` tag. No visitor would be on `http://www.example.com`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can do this with Craft’s [{% redirect %}](http://buildwithcraft.com/docs/templating/redirect) tag. Just put this in your /index.html template:

```twig
{% redirect 'news' %}
```

If you want to redirect to the latest entry in your News section, as you mentioned in the comments above, just fetch the entry first:

```twig
{% set latestNews = craft.entries.section('news').order('postDate desc').first() %}
{% redirect latestNews.url %}
```

Answer (score 4):

If you want one of your *channel entries* to be the homepage, simply include the channel entries' template to your home page `index.html`:

```
{# Set the `entry` variable manually #}
{% set entry = craft.entries.section('news').first() %}

{# Load the channel entry template #}
{% include "news/_entry" %}
```

With this setup, your visitors would actually be on your homepage's URL `http://www.example.com` instead of never really landing there.

You'd possibly even confuse some visitors, if they get redirected to `http://www.example.com/news/my-not-so-very-long-news-title` straight away and they might search for your proper home page?!

I'm not sure at all, but I can imagine a regularly changing redirect (each time you add a new news post you'd also have a new home URL!) could also by problematic for SEO rankings. Please correct me if I'm wrong with that!

Comment: Using this technique you would want to set a canonical url to the sections entry url so google didn't see duplicate content on your homepage AND the news entry page.

Comment: Right. Thanks for adding this here, @jnowland!

Answer (score 3):

*EDIT:*

*This answer was given when it wasn't yet clear that @shanti wants one of the channel entries to become the home page. The following is only relevant, if you want a channel's index page to be available under `http://www.example.com`.*

.

I'd recommend you to add a single section to your configuration as the entry for your channel's index. In this single's settings you select the template you currently use and you have a checkbox to make this single entry your home page!

Another idea would be to use one structure section for all *singular content pages* (e.g. about, contact, etc.) and all your channel *index pages* (e.g. projects, news). There are other interesting Q/As here on Stack Exchange on that topic. If you're going that way, have a look at the answers on ["Add home page to a structure?"](https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/q/1467/125)

If you simply want to redirect the visitors to `http://www.example.com/news`, there's a [`{% redirect %}`](http://buildwithcraft.com/docs/templating/redirect) tag available for such redirects.

Answer (score 2):

Another approach if you simply want to use a channel as your homepage (rather than redirecting) is to just make your homepage extend the channel's index template. For example, set your homepage template to:

```
{% extends "news/index" %}
```

...and the News channel will appear on your homepage.