# Make entry in nav not clickable and reroute

Tags: templating, navigation, redirect, reroute

I have an entry that acts as a parent to several children pages. Trying to make so that particular parent isn't clickable AND reroutes to homepage if address url is accessed.

Not sure if I can work something into existing nav code or if this needs to be done somewhere else, but here's the code, nonetheless. Thanks in advance.

```
<ul>
    {% set pages = craft.entries.section('page') %}
    {% nav page in pages %}
        <li>
            {{ page.getLink() }}
            {% ifchildren %}
                <ul>
                    {% children %}
                </ul>
            {% endifchildren %}
        </li>
    {% endnav %}
</ul>
```

Comment: You can use the redirect tag for this: http://buildwithcraft.com/docs/templating/redirect, something along the lines of {% redirect entry.children.first.uri %}

Comment: Maybe this solution works for you: ["Add home page to a structure?"](http://craftcms.stackexchange.com/q/1467/125)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `level` method to determine which iteration of the nav you are on and change the behavior:

```
<ul>
    {% set pages = craft.entries.section('page') %}
    {% nav page in pages %}
        <li>
            {% if page.level == 1 %}
                <a href="/">{{ page.title }}</a>
            {% else %}
                {{ page.getLink() }}
            {% endif %}
            {% ifchildren %}
                <ul>
                    {% children %}
                </ul>
            {% endifchildren %}
        </li>
    {% endnav %}
</ul>
```

of if it's only one particular entry, then you can create a conditional to check for that entry (using slug, id, title, or any other attribute or field value).

```
<ul>
    {% set pages = craft.entries.section('page') %}
    {% nav page in pages %}
        <li>
            {% if page.slug == "myPage" %}
                <a href="/">{{ page.title }}</a>
            {% else %}
                {{ page.getLink() }}
            {% endif %}
            {% ifchildren %}
                <ul>
                    {% children %}
                </ul>
            {% endifchildren %}
        </li>
    {% endnav %}
</ul>
```

If the url is accessed directly you can add a redirect to the template.

```
{% if entry.level == 1 %}
    {% redirect siteUrl %}
{% endif %}
```

Comment: The second snippet of code worked. The url redirect I used `entry.slug` for the redirect. Thank you for the help!