# Landing Page with Same URL Structure as Category

Tags: entries, categories, routes

I have a category group called "Resource Categories" and categories within it have their own urls.

Category Url Formats:

top-level categories: resources/{slug}
nested categories: {parent.uri}/{slug}

Category Template:
resources/_category

[image: Category Setup]

There's also a category template which is here:
resources/_entry

What I want to do is add a Landing page at /resources.

This would be a standard entry page ideally created within my Pages channel using the pages/_entry template.

Failing that I could also create an index page inside the resources folder.

But I keep getting 403 forbidden when visiting site.com/resources.

I've tried creating a route but that doesn't help the issue.

```
'resources' => 'pages/_entry'
```

Comment: This might be healpful


http://craftcms.stackexchange.com/questions/1467/add-home-page-to-a-structure

Answer (score 1):

You've hit on most of the options — all of which should work fine.

1. Assuming you have a structure called 'pages', with the 'uri' set to `{slug}`, 'parent uri' set to `{parent.uri}/{slug}`, and template set to 'pages/_entry'; create a new entry 'resources' which should route to your template at 'pages/_entry.html', or
2. If you do not have a 'pages' structure you can also just create a template at 'templates/resources.html', or 'templates/resources/index.html', or
3. Create a route `'resources' => 'pages/_entry'`

If those aren't working, then you might check that the template itself isn't creating any restrictions, and/or that you don't have any other routes defined (i.e. in your config file) that might be creating conflicts.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I figured out what it was. The client has a section/page entry called “resources” and guess what my folder for all the site resources (css/js/etc) is called? :)

Comment: That would do it! Didn't even think about that. Good catch.