# Display JavaScript only on the homepage

Tags: templating

What is the best method to render Javascript on specific page using name instead of id. This is what I found but not sure how to use name instead.

```
{% if entry.id == 2 %}
{% endif %}

{% if entry.section == homepage %}
    //Content goes here
{% endif %}
```

Answer (score 2):

You'd typically use the [`{% includeJs %}`](https://craftcms.com/docs/templating/includejs) or [`{% includeJsFile %}`](https://craftcms.com/docs/templating/includejsfile) tags within your page template, to specify your page-specific JavaScript, and then output everything in your layout template by calling [`{{ getFootHtml() }}`](https://craftcms.com/docs/templating/functions#getFootHtml).

Here's how your (very basic) page template might look in practice:

```
{# mypage.twig #}
{% extends '_layout' %}
{% includeJsFile "/assets/js/mypage.js" %}
```

And here's how your (equally basic) layout template might look:

```
{# _layout.twig #}
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head></head>
<body>

{# This outputs the JavaScript from mypage.twig #}
{{ getFootHtml() }}
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want something to only appear on the homepage you could use this:

```
{% if craft.request.lastSegment == "" %}
  {# do something #}
{% endif %}
```

Answer (score 2):

So the most reliable way to check to see if you're on the Craft-designated homepage (which can be either a Single, or a Structure, or what have you) would be:

```
{% if entry.slug == '__home__' %}
    //Content goes here
{% endif %}
```

As per: [Add home page to a structure?](https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/questions/1467/add-home-page-to-a-structure)

Rather than using `{% includeJs %}` or `{% includeJsFile %}` I would recommend that you use some kind of a JavaScript loader with dependency management:

[Using SystemJS as a JavaScript Loader](https://nystudio107.com/blog/using-systemjs-as-javascript-loader)

[LoadJS as a Lightweight JavaScript Loader](https://nystudio107.com/blog/loadjs-as-a-lightweight-javascript-loader)