# Possible to have a single entry page with multilingual slugs and only one index.html?

Tags: slug

How can I be able to have a single section page (so that clients can't create another one of this) that only needs 1 index.html template across different languages AND be accessible through following different slugs:

- x.dev/muziektoerisme
- x.dev/fr/tourisme-musical/
- x.dev/en/music-tourism/

I currently have a setup similar to this one: [Add home page to a structure?](https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/questions/1467/add-home-page-to-a-structure), which is a structure section 'Pages' with my custom page entry type 'musictourism' under 'craft/templates/_pages/_types/' (so 'musictourism.html' sits in this folder)
This works great, except for the fact that users are able to recreate a page of this entry type, which I don't want.

Does my question make any sense? Or am I missing something fundamental here? :) I'm new to Craft by the way.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're asking for is fine. Create a subfolder within your public directory for each locale with it's own index.php and define the new path to craft/ and the locale. For example, within public_html/fr/index.php you might have:

```
// Path to your craft/ folder
$craftPath = '../../craft';

// Tell Craft to serve the FRENCH content
define('CRAFT_LOCALE', 'fr');
```

With the single, you set the slug yourself within the section's settings (one slug for each locale that section is available to).

Comment: Hi, thank you for your reply! I had already configured the language folders, so that wasn't the issue :) I guess I forgot to configure the single's slug in multiple languages, like you mentioned in the last paragraph of your comment. Thanks!

Comment: Easy mistake to make.